# How do I return JSON data compatible with the Boost module?

Tags: 7, ajax, caching

In a custom module a, I return a JSON string that needs to be compatible with the Boost module.

My first try was using the following code:

```
if ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 'XMLHttpRequest' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?json') !== FALSE) {
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
  header('Content-type: application/json', true);
  $json = loadData();
  die(json_encode($json));
}
```

This is obviously that this output won't be cached. Than I replaced the line with `die()` with the following one:

```
return drupal_json_output(($json));
```

This works, but it is not cached. I enabled the JSON output in Boost, but nothing happens.

What should I try?

---

Removing the two `header` lines does not change anything. The function `drupal_json_output` adds the `Content-Type: application/json`. But I belive that boost only accepts `text/javascript`. Also if I override the `Content-Type` again nothing will be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add

module_invoke_all('exit');

to the template-file, immediately prior to the `exit` or `die` statement.
This will trigger the boost-module's code that stores the generated output in a cache-file.
Additionally, you need to change the content-type to `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to cache `JSON` output? Anyhow, try removing `header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');` and see what happens.

Comment: I tried that. No changes. I need that because drupal needs about 1.2 seconds to response and this is annoying.

Comment: Did you tried like this:

`if(( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
     && 'XMLHttpRequest' == $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']
   ) || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '?json')!==FALSE) {
    header('Content-type: application/json', true);
    $json=loadData();
    return drupal_json_output(($json));
}`

Comment: Tried to clear cache?

Comment: Ehm after flushing the cache boost stoped to work. Nothing is cached at the moment...

Comment: Yep, It needs to rebuild the content. Anyhow `JSON` should not be cached, because you won't get real-time data. Otherwise - consider other format for content delivery.

Comment: I forgot to logout. Boost works again but no changes. To override the Content-Type to text/javascript doesn't work as well I thought maybe that boost expects that content type. Is there an other way make drupal faster? IMHO 1.2 is much to long.

Comment: Yes, answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/5131/6755

Comment: @Zydrunas I disagree. There's nothing wrong with caching JSON content if the underlying data is static (or nearly do). JSON is great for client-side jQuery-based sites that need a persistent backend.

Answer (score 0):

Boost currently doesn't support `application/json` Content-Type. See [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1219484) for details and patches.

Comment: I stopped using Boost but that makes sense, why that did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might help others who are trying to have Boost cache JSON data.

Boost wont cache **"application/json"**, but there are settings to cache TEXT/JAVASCRIPT AJAX request of type **"text/javascript"**

One problem you are going to find with : **drupal_json_output()**
It uses : **drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'application/json');**

So a solution you can try is this :

```
$data = array("hello","world");
drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
echo drupal_json_encode($data);
drupal_exit();
```

So if you have Boost "AJAX/JSON SETTINGS" enabled it should now cache the data.